# Play Framework not compiling

Tags: java, playframework

I have an application which uses play framework. I am trying to start using the activator command **"activator clean compile run"** on compiling the code it is showing the error

> object Html is not a member of package play.api.templates [error]
>   import play.api.templates.{Html, Txt}

Any idea how to fix this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably trying to run code written for an earlier version of Play with Play 2.4. `play.api.templates.Html` has been deprecated in Play 2.3 and has apparently been removed in 2.4.

From the [Play 2.3 Package documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.templates.package) for `Html`:

> Deprecated
>
> (Since version 2.3.0) Use play.twirl.api.Html

You can also refer to the [Templates section of the Play 2.3 migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23#Templates).

The [Play version which is used](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Build#Play-plugin-for-sbt-(/project/plugins.sbt)) is defined in project/plugins.sbt. The relevant plugin is "com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin".

Comment: how can we revert back to play version 2.3

Comment: Think i have to migrate my code to the newer version.

Comment: If you have a new project, I think this is a good idea. Nevertheless, I've added the info on where the Play version is configured.